# Simple way to iterate and transfer data from linear array to array of vec3

Tags: c++

Simple way of transferring data from linear array to an array of vec3?

```
int stride = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < vertex_count; i++)
        {
            s_vertex[i].active = false;
            s_vertex[i].x = vertex_array[0+stride];
            s_vertex[i].y = vertex_array[1+stride];
            s_vertex[i].z = vertex_array[2+stride];
            stride += 3;
        }
```

Obviously this prompts exception because it overshoots an index into array, which is the goal here, to not overshoot.

Comment: Please show a [mcve]. What is a `vec3` and what are the size of the relevant arrays?

Comment: We cant answer. The question because the title is asking how to transfer data and the question itself is asking how not to index out of bounds of the array (but we dont know what the sizes of them are). Could you clarify the question and provide the missing information if any? (P.S: if vertex_array is 3x the size of vertex_count it should work. P.P.S: you can get rid of stride and replace by i*3)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, please take a moment to review the tour: [stackoverflow.com/tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), *How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example*: [stackoverflow.com/help/mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and *How to Ask Good Questions* [stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) - you'll get better feedback and helpful answers if you put some thought in to your problem before coming to SO for help, and by including a specific problem with code that you've tried showing effort to solve the problem yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can resolve this couple of ways.

1. Adjust the index to the `std::vector`.

   ```
   int stride = 3;
   for (int i = 0; i < vertex_count; i += stride )
   {
      // Making up the class name of the elements of the vector.
      ElementType element;

      element.active = false;
      element.x = vertex_array[0+i];
      element.y = vertex_array[1+i];
      element.z = vertex_array[2+i];

      // Index for the vector.
      int i2 = i/stride;
      s_vertex[i2] = element;
   }
   ```

   PS. Please note a slight change to how `stride` is used.
2. Use `std::vector::push_back` instead of indexing into it.

   ```
   int stride = 3;
   for (int i = 0; i < vertex_count; i += stride )
   {
      ElementType element;
      element.active = false;
      element.x = vertex_array[0+i];
      element.y = vertex_array[1+i];
      element.z = vertex_array[2+i];
      s_vertex.push_back(element);
   }
   ```

   To minimize the number of memory allocations and deallocations, it's a good idea to use `std::vector::reserve` first before loop begins so that the calls to `push_back` don't need to allocate memory.

   ```
   int stride = 3;
   s_vertex.reserve(vertex_count/3);
   for (int i = 0; i < vertex_count; i += stride )
   {
      ElementType element;
      element.active = false;
      element.x = vertex_array[0+i];
      element.y = vertex_array[1+i];
      element.z = vertex_array[2+i];
      s_vertex.push_back(element);
   }
   ```

Comment: If you are going to suggest `push_back` it is good practice to `reserve` first.

Answer (score 0):

```
struct vertexs {
    bool active;
    int x, y, z;
};

if((vertex_count % 3) != 0)
    printf("ERROR: Your array is not evenly disctibuted....")

int i = 0;
while ( i < vertex_count)
{
    vertexs v;
    v.actice = false;
    v.x = vertex_array[i++];
    v.y = vertex_array[i++];
    v.z = vertex_array[i++];
    s_vertex.push_back(v);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For something cheap to default construct like a `vec3` you can resize the target array to the required size and then loop though and assign values much like you have done:

```
s_vertex.resize(vertex_array.size() / 3);
int i = 0;
for (auto& v : s_vertex) {
  v.x = vertex_array[i];
  v.y = vertex_array[i + 1];
  v.z = vertex_array[i + 2];
  i += 3;
}
```

[Live demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/LMjs3cooQhfuebiS).